# Database in ionic ios app?

Tags: angularjs, database, ionic-framework

I have to develop a simple app with ionic for ios and I am not really sure how to implement the model of my app.
I need to read some data and the user have to be able to save some data alse.
The app might be able to work offline also.

Any idea? I think firebase only supports offline in ios and android but not with web.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

what you need is  persistent data storages.
localforage is one of many

https://github.com/localForage/localForage